# How to get the stylesheets from a manually created document?

Tags: javascript, html, stylesheet, document

If I run the following:

```
document.styleSheets
```

I get an object containing some stylesheets.

If I clone the current document like this:

```
const clone = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument ();
clone.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

And then run the following:

```
clone.styleSheets
```

I no longer get the stylesheets. How can I overcome this issue? I can't actually render the content of the cloned document anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As a shoddy workaround, you could set the cloned document's stylesheets to the previous document's stylesheets.

This may or may not work depending on how js deepcloning works.

Comment: Welcome, please take a moment to read: [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)